# Angular growl module implementation issue

Tags: angular

I am learning angular 2 js.
I have to add a module that show growl notification at my angular app i have added module in my app.module but it gives me the error below:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'GrowlModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at compiler.es5.js:15398
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Module Url : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-growl

and my app.module.ts code is like :

```
import {GrowlModule} from 'ng2-growl';
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LeftPanelComponent,
    MainPanelComponent,
    CategoriesComponent,
    AuthenticateComponent,
    PageheaderComponent,
    SubCategoriesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    GrowlModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  providers: [
  AuthService,
  CookieService,
  AuthGuard,  
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what exception message tells you to?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov as i have said i am new for angular so i have not understood what i need to do

Comment: I have change GrowlModule to GrowlModule.forRoot()
i shows me error like:
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at compiler.es5.js:15398
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

Comment: have you included this line on top `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';`??

Comment: @JayDeeEss yes i have include it on top